# What is $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{r+2}{2^{r+1}(r)(r+1)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find out the sum of the following infinite series
$$\frac{3}{2^2(1)(2)} + \frac{4}{2^3(2)(3)} +\dots+\frac{r+2}{2^{r+1}(r)(r+1)}+\cdots
$$
up to $r\to\infty$.

MY TRY:-  I tried to split $r+2$ as $[(r+1) +{(r+1)-r}]$ so that I can cancel one term from each terms in the numerator. Then I got an expression which was like Harmonic-Geometric series. But I could not do further any more after this.

Comment: Hint: rth term is same as $\frac{1}{r *2^r}-\frac{1}{ (r+1) * 2^{r+1}}$ so you were already pretty close. A split of $2*(r+1)-r$ thus would have been more beneficial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do the partial fraction expansion, the summand becomes

$$\frac{1}{2^{r+1}}\left( \frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{r+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2^r r} - \frac{1}{2^{r+1}(r+1)},   $$

So the sequence is telescoping.  All terms cancel except the first and so sum equals $\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

prove by induction that for your sum is hold $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i+2}{2^{i+1}i(i+1)}=\frac{2^{-n-1} \left(2^n n+2^n-1\right)}{n+1}$$